# Rewrite part of url with .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I need to rewrite URL and save top level domain and query.

I tried to use these rules

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^domain(.*)$ http://newdomain$1 [R=302,NE,L]
```

Using [this testing tool](http://htaccess.mwl.be/) I found that it works if **domain.com/query?param=value** is used as a request URL. But if I try to use **http://domain.com/query?param=value**[ it doesn't work.

Basically I don't care what protocol is (http or https), I just need to replace first occurrence of **domain** string and rewrite it with *newdomain* saving all other parts of a request URL.

Answer (score 1):

As it turned out in your comment to the first answer I gave you are actually trying to replace only *part* of the hostname of the incoming request but keep path and query string. That was not clear to me from your question, sorry.

You have to use an additional `RewriteCond` for this, since as said before you caanot access the hostname at all inside a `RewriteRule`. So I guess the following goes into the direction of what you are actually looking for:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^\.]+\.(.+)$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^newdomain\.(.+)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$       http://newdomain.%1/$1   [R=301,L,QSA]
```

You may want to try this modification to preserve the original request scheme too:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^\.]+\.(.+)$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^newdomain\.(.+)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$       %{REQUEST_SCHEME}://newdomain.%1/$1   [R=301,L,QSA]
```

Comment: Both variants outputs `http://olddomain.com/://newdomain.com/:/newdomain.com/:/newdomain.com/:/newdomain.com/...`

Actually I made redirects with PHP already but still wonder if it's possible with .htaccess.

Comment: Indeed, that looks like a redirection loop and so a second `RewriteCond` is required. I modified the two examples as required.

Comment: The second condition looks reasonable but the result is the same as in my previous comment.

Comment: Maybe a caching issue? Try a "deep reload" in your browser or clear the browser cache.

Comment: Unfortunately the same with cleaned cache, in private browser window and in an another clean browser.

Comment: Strange... I suggest you raise the rewrite log level and check inside the http servers rewrite log file what is going on inside the rewrite engine. You can log very detailed information about each step tried and done by that engine.